# Set font color active when clicked in HTML

Tags: html, css

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container flex-lg-column">
            <a class="navbar-brand mx-lg-auto mb-lg-4" href="#home">
                <span class="h3 fw-bold d-block d-lg-none">My Career Prospect</span>
                <img src="../photos/intro.jpg" class="d-none d-lg-block rounded-circle" alt="">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-lg-column text-lg-center">

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../index/index.HTML">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../Experience/Experience.html">Experience</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../career/Career.html">Career Option</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="../Feedback/Feedback.html">Feedback</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <img src="../photos/moon.png" id="icon">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

```
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus {
    color: var(--color-brand);
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to set either the "Home", "Experience", "Career Option", "Feedback" font colour to "--color-brand" when it is selected. However, I'm not sure why the above code doesn't work as intended. Please help.

```
.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-link:active {
    color: var(--color-brand);
}
```

I have also tried using this

Comment: selected as in when it is active ?

Comment: Yup, when it is active

Comment: so I checked by focus it means when you click it or when you tab through things it works [here](https://jsfiddle.net/745Lspwj/). You can change the :focus to :hover and check that it still works

Comment: I want the color to stay after clicking it

Comment: I dont think your solution solves me issue

Comment: What i'm trying to figure out is why I cant get the result i want even though it works

Comment: I’m confused. This is a navigation bar, and activating a link will lead you away from that page. So whatever selector you find, wouldn’t it be inactive after page load? Active navigation links should a) not be links, so not have `href`, and b) have `aria-current="page"` on them. See the [bootstrap navbar documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/)

Comment: The navigation bar is fixed at the top of the page, there is 4 pages. I want to let the user know which page they are on. That is why i want the respective pages to have a colour active after the user clicks on it

Comment: This is achieved by adding `aria-current="page"` to the active page, as per bootstrap documentation.

Comment: What backend are you using? Or is this a single page application driven by javascript and a router only?